# How to access and change Spinners and Checkboxes in a ListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, checkbox, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am creating a smart house and in the edit page I need to preload the spinner and checkboxes with the values that the user inputed before. I cant seem to access them.
they are in a listview with an array adapter. Is there a different way to access them?

the code where i am trying to access the spinner:

```
 ArrayAdapter arScenarioOn = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.layout_dropdown_add,ComboPage.options.toArray());
    
        programAdapter = new ComboAddAdapter(this, Items.area,Items.progImag, isChecked,arScenarioOn);
        applianceListview.setAdapter(programAdapter);
    
    
        groupNameTil.getEditText().setText(name);
    
    
       for (int i = 0; i < programAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            Spinner d = programAdapter.getView(i,null,applianceListview).findViewById(R.id.spinner_scenario);
            TextView dview = programAdapter.getView(i,null,applianceListview).findViewById(R.id.textView_title_group);
            dview.setText("I win");
           //applianceListview.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.spinner_scenario);
           d.setSelection(2);
        }
```

Code for the single item in list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:visibility="visible"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_group"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/picture_lightbuldyellow" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_title_group"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/title"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_scenario"
            android:layout_width="117dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"

            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textSize="8sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:outlineAmbientShadowColor="@color/green"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/green"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If you can access that TextView then accessing the spinner and checkbox go in the same way.

Comment: But what do you need exactly? If you wanna change values then you should change values in the lists and arrays of the adapter. And having done that call notifyDatasetChanged(). Do not touch the listview itself.

Comment: For the checkboxes i could change the list, but for the spinner i want to change to off/on, and for that i need to access each spinner and change its value. And i cant seem to access them

Comment: `For the checkboxes i could change the list,` Which list? The ListView or a list of the adapter? Please be exact!

Comment: You should arrange in the adapters lists and arrays not only the value for the spinners but also their state on/off. And then if needed change on/off for a specific spinnner in the list of the adapter. And then call notifyDataSetChanged() or notifyItemChanged(). It makes no sense to change the spinner in the ListView as when you scroll and scroll back the change will be lost.